# Fast zip extraction/text parsing from memory in Android

Tags: java, c#, android

I'm trying to port a C# program to Android. The program downloads a ~100MB zip file, which contains a few tightly-compressed multiple-gigabytes text files. I need to find a specific line in a specific file in that archive. Since disk I/O would be absolutely devastating at these sizes, and because I am limited in RAM (so I cannot just extract everything to memory), I implemented this in C# by saving the entire archive in RAM (100MB, still fine), wrapping the buffer in a MemoryStream which is then encapsulated in a ZipArchive stream, and then I access the specific file's stream via GetEntry(), which I encapsulate in a StreamReader and from there I can just sequentially read and search for the data.

I tried doing something like that in Android using Java, however ZipInputStream does not allow me to quickly seek to the file I want in the archive (since I have to loop on getNextEntry, which seems to just extract everything by the time it takes to return) and ZipFile doesn't accept memory streams as input.

Is there a way to do that in Android? If not, is there a different, more android-ish way to do what I'm trying without a huge performance hit?